# Выбор языка для GUI запросов к БД

Tags: sql, любой-язык

Есть гигантская oracle sql БД на проекте, который я тестирую. Ежедневно к этой БД приходится писать сложные запросы. Я уже накопила шаблонов запросов штук 50, но все равно получается слишком много телодвижений для их использования.
Я не программист, но немного хотела бы, поэтому придумала в свободное время сделать простую интерфейсную штуку, в которой я бы вводила только параметры запроса к БД, и получала ответы (например, выбрать параметр, второй параметр и количество результатов в респонсе). Сверстать простую html страницу я могу. Но не представляю как прикрутить к ней sql-запросы. Подозреваю, что при помощи JS, но не уверена, поэтому пришла за советом.
За знакомство с каким языком программирования нужно браться, чтобы сделать GUI-инструмент (можно браузерный) для облегченной работы с БД?

Answer (score 1):

> Сверстать простую html страницу я могу. Но не представляю как
>   прикрутить к ней sql-запросы. Подозреваю, что при помощи JS, но не
>   уверена, поэтому пришла за советом.

К html sql Вы никак не прикрутите. Это язык разметки, а не программирования. С JS такое возможно только на сервере (Node.js).

В принципе для такой задачи может подойти любая платформа поддерживающая доступ к БД. Хоть Node.js, хоть PHP, хоть Java, хоть что угодно.

В прочем, можно поискать и готовые программные продукты для упрощённой работы с запросами.

Comment: для php и js сервера нужно ставить и настраивать что не очень удобно, лучше скачать java и установить eclipse с плагином window builder потом к проекту добавить библиотеку для работы с нужной базой и вперед :)